# Simplify parent-child expression with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript object such as this:

```
{
    a : {
        b : c,
        d : e
    }
}
```

In my code, if `b` my was my starting point, I could input the string `"this.$parent.d"` which would evaluate to `e`.

However I could also input the string `"this.$parent.b.$parent.d"` to get the same result.

My question is if I am given a string such as `"this.$parent.b.$parent.d"` how can I simplify it to the first way?

I think what I need to do is use regex to replace all occurrences of `"$parent.<anything>.$parent"` with just `"$parent"` and that should work but not sure how to do this exactly.

Comment: I'm confused about your parent/child relationship. In your first instance, `this.$parent` is the containing object, which allows you to call `.d`. But then in the second instance, you are calling `this.$parent.b`, which means `this.$parent` resolves to `a`?

Comment: Sorry editted now to fix the JSON

Comment: Okay that makes more sense now. So basically, you want to replace `this.$parent.[not $parent].$parent.*` with simply `this.$parent.*` You want to leave `.$parent.$parent` because that's how you get to the next level up in the hierarchy

Comment: yes that sounds right

Comment: But `b` has no idea who its parent is.

Comment: in my case it does know but that's not the concern of this question anyway, more about the simplification with regex

Comment: Does `.replace(/\.\$parent\.[^$]\.\$parent/g, ".$parent")` work for you?

Comment: @user2802557 Check if my solution is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you'll want to simplify an even shorter expression:

```
.prop.$parent
```

Such a substring should be removed, since it is a no-operation.

Here is how you could do that with a regular expression:

```js
function simplify(str) {
    const expression = /\.(?!\$parent\.)[\w$]+\.\$parent(?=\.|$)/g;
    while (str.length > (str = str.replace(expression, "")).length) {}
    return str; 
}

var strings = [
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.d",                     // should be this.$parent.d
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.d.$parent.b.$parent.b", // should be this.$parent.b
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.$parent.b.$parent",     // should be this.$parent.$parent
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.d.$parent.$parent.b",   // should be this.$parent.$parent.b
   "this.$parent.b.c.$parent.$parent.b",           // should be this.$parent.b
   "this.$parentX.b.$parentX",                     // should be this.$parentX.b.$parentX
];

const results = strings.map(simplify);
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex you're looking for is this:

`/\.\$parent\.[^$]?[^p]?[^a]?[^r]?[^e]?[^n]?[^t]?\.\$parent/g`

Someone who is better at regex than me can hopefully simplify this, since it seems very verbose.

The solution below uses a recursive function, because if there are two instances that get replaced in the same string, you have now created another instance of `.$parent.*.$parent`, which needs to then get replaced with just `.$parent`.

For example:

`this.$parent.b.$parent.d.$parent.$parent.b`

After 1 `.replace()` --> `this.$parent.d.$parent.$parent.b`

After 2 `.replace()` --> `this.$parent.$parent.b`

Here's the code in action:

```js
var expression = /\.\$parent\.[^$]?[^p]?[^a]?[^r]?[^e]?[^n]?[^t]?\.\$parent/g;

var strings = [
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.d",                     // should be this.$parent.d
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.d.$parent.b.$parent.b", // should be this.$parent.b
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.$parent.b.$parent",     // should be this.$parent.$parent
   "this.$parent.b.$parent.d.$parent.$parent.b"    // should be this.$parent.$parent.b
];

function simplify (str) {
    var str = str.replace(expression, ".$parent");
    if (expression.test(str)) {
        return simplify(str);
    }
    return str;
}

strings.forEach(function (str) {
  console.log(simplify(str));
});
```